# Grab a form data with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to do a simple form mail with ajax.
But, I can't grab the data from the form.

My form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Page', array('default' => false)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('texto', array('label' => FALSE, 'type' => 'textarea)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('Enviar', array('id' => 'enviar'));
        echo $this->Form->end();
```

My ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#enviar').click(function(){
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  complete: function(r){
    $('div.teste').html('<h4> Enviado!</h4>');
  }
  })
 })
});
```

The controller:

```
    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    debug($this->request->data);

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
$Email->to('xxxx@gmail.com');
$Email->subject('Nova Mensagem - Site Althi');
$Email->send($mensagem);

            }

}
```

And my controller send the email.
The e-mail has send sucefull, but the data of `this->request->data` is a blank array.
I think the problem is the data passed from the ajax.
Can help me please?

Comment: I don't see `this->request->data` anywhere in your script.

Comment: edited with the controller

Comment: Is `$mensagem` in your form?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `data` value in the ajax function call.

```
$.ajax(
    thecontrollerurl,
    {data: $("#theformid").serialize()}
);
```

more info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I don't use cakephp, but I believe it should be similar to your ordinary controller handling post/get request. try to debug the request data.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = $this->Js->get('#YourformORelementID')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
```

And then

```
$this->Js->get('#enviar');
$this->Js->event('click', 
$this->Js->request(
    array('controller' => 'someController', 'action' => 'someAction'),
    array('async' => true, 'data' => $data, 'update' => 'div.teste')
));
```